# Python 3 - colon expected error in If and line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a line of code like this:

if fpod >=1and <=3:

However there is a line under "<=3:" that says colon expected?

I am trying to test between values of 1 and 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic syntax is wrong. Both sides of the and statement must evaluate to a Boolean on there own so

```
 if fpod >=1 and fpod <=3:
```

however

```
 if 1 <= fpod <=3:
```

is a legal statement.

Comment: thank you. This was the problem and the code above has resolved it.